# Extracting LAS/LAZ info in a performant way with PDAL?

Tags: python, lidar, open-source-gis, pdal

I can do this:

```
import json
import subprocess as sp

laz_file = somefile.laz
r = (sp.run(['pdal', 'info', laz_file], stderr=sp.PIPE, stdout=sp.PIPE))
json_info = json.loads(r.stdout.decode())
```

and parse through the JSON, get the info I need (EPSG code and min/max x/y).  It does "work."

However calling this workflow on a laz file, especially when some of mine are over 1 gb, takes significantly longer than a las file.  As I am iterating over hundreds of laz files (which change daily and sometimes hourly) and intending the output to be used as a dynamic map tracker for our holdings.

How can I extract the EPSG code and the bounding box in a more performant way?

Comment: Where's the bottleneck?  If you're IO bound, use faster storage if you can.  If you're not IO or memory bound, try using multiprocessing.  You could also see if [lasinfo](https://github.com/LAStools/LAStools) is any quicker than pdal, if it provides the info you need.

Comment: Have you worked with pgpointcloud? Check out `PC_Summary()` https://github.com/pgpointcloud/pointcloud

Comment: @mikewatt it's the pdal --stats routine itself, but only on laz files.  Run against very large las files, it is quick.  So it seems like there is some decompress-to-memory going on that is very slow.  I am running this all across 10gb fibre to nvme isilon, so I can't imagine storage IO is the bottleneck.

Comment: @Aaron that is really intriguing but as I am in a tightly controlled enterprise environment that does not run PG, I will need solutions that let me interrogate data at rest on the san without postgresql.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [doc](https://pdal.io/apps/info.html)  of `pdal info`:

> If no options are provided, --stats is assumed.

This means that you need to read the entire point cloud to derive information that you don't actually need. What you are looking for is in the metadata of the file (the header). You don't need to read the payload (the points) at all. Try

```
pdal info file.las --metadata
```

This will return your info (epsg, bbox) virtually instantaneously. You will maybe need a bit more parsing however. The EPSG code is stored is the Variable Length Record (VLR) with a key `"LASF_Projection"`. Should look like that.

```
"vlr_0":
{
  "data": "AQABAAAABQAABAAAAQABAAAMAAABAIkLBAwAAAEAKSMDEAAAAQApIwAQAAABAGcE",
  "description": "by LAStools of rapidlasso GmbH",
  "record_id": 34735,
  "user_id": "LASF_Projection"
},
```

The bounding box can be found at the begining

```
"maxx": 684993.29,
"maxy": 5018007.25,
"maxz": 29.97,
"minor_version": 2,
"minx": 684766.39,
"miny": 5017773.08,
"minz": 0,
```

Comment: You are partially right.  It returns the XY extents, but only as line/sample, not as geocoordinates like `--stats` does.  And it *appears* to return the spatial reference as a huge text brick inside of one element - the SRS info itself not being serialized. I'm probably missing something.

Comment: Does my edit clarifies the anwser?

Comment: So is the `record_id` value the EPSG code?

Comment: Yes. For LAS file < 1.4 at least. For LAS file 1.4 the CRS is recorded as WKT string.

Comment: Ah...this looks really promising, thank you!  I'll run a few tests and report back.

Comment: So as it turns out that is not the horizontal EPSG. The right EPSG code is not directly accessible as a metadata key-value pair. It is stashed in `metadata: {'comp_spatialreference`value, as the `AUTHORITY` that is direct child of `PROJCS[]`.  I am not familiar with how best to parse `COMPD_CS` info though; it may be worth writing something new but I wouldn't want to do that if a module somewhere exists to do it already.

Comment: Need to see the entire output. Open a new question.

Comment: Sorry, so it looks like I can pull the entire `comp_spatialreference` value into a `pyproj.CRS.from_wkt()` object.  Thanks!

Comment: Yes, PDAL will interpret the CRS VLRs from LAS data for you and stash them in the metadata as various WKT flavors. Note that issuing `--metadata` does not read the actual points, and it is common to have the header advertise different extrema than the point data actually contain.